# Android AlertDialog inside an anonymous function

Tags: android, function, dialog, alert, anonymous

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog that opens when an item is click in my listview.  However, the constructor of the AlertDialog requires a context, but "this" won't work because it points to the anonymous function.  I tried "getApplicationContext()" and "getBaseContext()" but the application crashes.

Any ideas?

```
    // Open stored preferences page
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    // Load stored data key/value pairs
    Map<String, String> savedData = (Map<String, String>) settings.getAll();

    // Populate the list view in the activity with the stored data keys
    ListView lSavedData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lDataList);

    ArrayAdapter arrAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, savedData.keySet().toArray(new String[0]) );
    lSavedData.setAdapter( arrAdap );

    lSavedData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Prepare a function selection menu for when the user selects a data item 
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );

            alertBuilder.setTitle("What would you like to do?");

            final CharSequence[] dialogOptions =  {"Load", "Delete"};

            alertBuilder.setItems( dialogOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dialogOptions[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog functionDialog = alertBuilder.create();

            functionDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loaded " + ((TextView) arg1).getText() + " data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `YourActivityClassName.this`, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a dialog in an activity, you always get context of that activity.For ex: you create dialog in Activity A.with Context parameter you only need set A.his.:)